# How to insert multiple select input with same name

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to insert multiple value with same input name? My problem is that I am receiving multiple values.

```
<div class="giftcard box">
    <select name="price" id="colorselector2" style="width:150px;">
        <option value="">Select Gift Card Price</option>
        @foreach($productDetails->giftattributes as $price)
        <option value="{{$price->price}}">$ {{$price->price}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="giftcertificate box">
    <select name="price" id="colorselector" style="width:150px;">
        <option value="">Select Gift Certificate Price</option>
        @foreach($productDetails->giftattributes as $price)
        <option value="{{$price->price}}">$ {{$price->price}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="productasgift box">
    <select name="price" id="colorselector1" style="width:150px;">
        <option value="">Select Product As Gift Certificate</option>
        @foreach($allproduct as $allprice)
        <option value="{{$allprice->price}}">$ {{$allprice->price}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `name="price[]"`. That will send an array of price items to your server.

Comment: can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: dexter@I wan to insert this data on radio check,

Comment: If these answers helped you, please mark one as _accepted_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding `[]` at the end of the name, in the request then all the select/input with the same name should be in an array